# How to detect unused custom fields

Tags: apex, custom-field, eclipse

I'm trying develop a system that will detect which custom fields are no longer used such that they can be removed. To be more specific:
 1.) How can I determine if a custom field is used on a layout?
 2.) How can I find if a custom field is visible?
 3.) Are there are any other means I should check, and if so how?

Note: Im new to SF dev, but not new to coding. Im thinking of using apex via eclipse after importing the relevant information.

Comment: Also Google and take a look at the Metadata and Tooling APIs. These let you read the relevant information on the fly via web service calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Fieldtrip](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4) free app exchange app. This utility lets you analyze the fields of any object, including what percentage of the records (or a subset of your records) have that field populated.

- Find out how often fields are being used
- Run Reports on fields
- Analyze all or a subset of your records

Once installed, click the "Field Trip" tab to get started, then create a new Field Trip Record by giving it a name, selecting an object (e.g. Accounts) and optionally a filter (in case you don't want to process all records in the data base).

Once you use the "Analyze" button, you will see the "Field Analyses" related list on your Field Trip populated with records that represent every field on that object. This allows you to run and export reports on the fields for that object... including a column that tells you how many records have that field populated, and what percentage of the records that is.

Comment: Yes that's a nice idea. One of my colleagues developed this app and this app works like a charm. Go for it..!!

Comment: Are you saying this tool addresses the question posed i.e. 1) and 2)?

Answer (score 0):

It is a great product. Here's a sample analysis of my (Conference Event) Venue__c object.  Relative to the specifics of your request, a benefit of FieldTrip is that you;ll see the object field utilization rate regardless of whether or not the field appears on a given Page Layout.

[image: Field Trip Analysis Results - distribution of completeness by field, sorted descneding]

link to full-size image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32KzXlGqb49OXRUVFVNR3czc3c/view?usp=sharing